# MySql GMT Dates and Timezones

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have php application where I store event dates in GMT +0000 within a timestamp field (mySQL). Please ignore the bulk of the code below as it comes from a function where I am dealing with other timezones - its just to show that I am converting any date input to GMT +0000 for storage in the db. For the purposes of this question the offset = 0.

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$myDateTime = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i'), $gmtTimezone);
$offset = $userTimezone->getOffset($myDateTime);
$event_date = date('Y-m-d H:i', $myDateTime->format('U') + $offset);
$q = "insert into time_zone(dtime) values('".event_date."')";
$r = mysql_query($q);
```

And this seems to work well. So even if my server is running in the USA the date stored in the field is London date/time.

Now my challange is this. My clients need to locate events that occured within a date/time zone but they will work on their own timezone. For example Pacific/Auckland (GMT + 13).

So if the client enters in a search date of start "2010-12-30 00:01" and an end date for the search of "2010-12-30 23:01" how do I pass in a SQL statement that basically tells the database to search for values in the date field (stored as GMT + 0000) but add 13 hours (or negative) since the timezone is Pacific/Auckland. Is there an mySQL way of doing this taking into account Daylight savings etc...

So if a GMT date of "2010-12-30 08:17:00" is stored and my client living in Auckland searches with the dates above this record "2010-12-30 08:17:00" should come up because GMT +13 covers the search.

Answer (score 1):

The client should convert the datetimes from local time to GMT / UTC before sending them to database.

Comment: Hello Mark. Thanks for the quick reply. The "client" in this case being my code needs to accept the clients date requirements for the search - I know the clients timezone so I somehow need to minus the offset from the search dates which in my case would be 13 hours. Is this correct? And if so I think there are negative offset values so I would have to minus the offset?

Comment: A code example would be great! Maybe I should use the DateTime object to convert the local time to GMT?

Comment: @Marc: Yes from PHP you could look at `setTZByID` and `convertTZByID`.

Comment: Thank you Mark - you are very helpful. I think I have it done.

Comment: @Marc: By the way there is a CONVERT_TZ function in MySQL too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz - if your timezone information is stored in the database you might find this more convenient, but IMHO the sooner you convert datetimes to UTC, the better.